# Aggregate dummy variables to multiple categorical variables

Tags: stata

I have 8 dummy variables (0/1). Those 8 variables have to be aggregated to one categorical variable with 8 items (categories). Normally, people should have just marked one out of the 8 dummy variables, but some marked multiple ones.

When a Person has marked two items, the first value should go into the first categorical variable, whereas the second value should go to the second categorical variable. When there are 3 items marked, the third values should go into a third categorical variable and so on (up to 3).

I know how to aggregate the dummies to a categorical variable, but I do not know which approach there is to divide the values to different variables, based on the number of marked dummies.

If the problem is not clear, please tell me. It was difficult for me to describe it properly.

Edit:
**My approach is the follwoing:**

```
local MCM_zahl4 F0801 F0802 F0803 F0804 F0805 F0806 F0807 F0808
gen MCM_zaehl_4 = 0
foreach var of varlist `MCM_zahl4' {
    replace MCM_zaehl_4 = MCM_zaehl_4 + 1 if `var' == 1
}  

tab MCM_zaehl_4

/*

MCM_zaehl_4 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |         31        4.74        4.74
          1 |        598       91.44       96.18
          2 |         22        3.36       99.54
          3 |          3        0.46      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        654      100.00

*/

gen bildu2    = -999999
gen bildu2_D    = -999999
replace bildu2  = 1  if F0801 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 2  if F0802 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 3  if F0803 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 4  if F0804 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 5  if F0805 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 6  if F0806 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 7  if F0807 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
replace bildu2  = 8  if F0808 == 1 & MCM_zaehl_4 == 1
```

Then I split all cases MCM_zaehl_4 > 1 manually in three variables.
E. g. for two mcm:

```
replace bildu2   = 5 if ID == XXX
replace bildu2_D = 2 if ID == XXX
```

For that approach I'd need an auomation, because for more observations I won't be able to do it manually.

Comment: I think you're saying that you don't know how to aggregate, in which case this is not yet a programming problem.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your input. I think I have an idea how to do it, but only when I do some manual cleaning afterwards. I added the code I will use, if I am not able to automate the process.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail, but I don't understand enough of what you're doing to offer an answer.

Comment: @InPanic, did the solution provided help you with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could try the following to aggregate your multiples dummy variables into multiple aggregate columns based on the number of answers that the person marked. It assumes the repeated answers are consecutive. I reduced your problem to 6 dummy (`a1-a6`) and people can answer up to 3 questions.

```
clear

input id a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 
      1  1  0   0  0  0  0
      2  1  1   0  0  0  0
      3  1  1   1  0  0  0
      4  1  1   1  0  0  0
      5  0  1   0  0  0  0
      6  1  0   0  0  0  0
      7  0  0   0  0  1  0
      8  0  0   0  0  0  1
end

egen n_asnwers = rowtotal(a*)

gen wanted_1 = .
gen wanted_2 = .
gen wanted_3 = .

local i = 1
foreach v of varlist a* {
    replace wanted_1 = `v' if `v' == 1 & n_asnwers == 1
    replace wanted_2 = `v' if `v' == 1 & n_asnwers == 2
    replace wanted_3 = `v' if `v' == 1 & n_asnwers == 3 

local ++i
}

list

/*  
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   n_asnw~s   wanted_1   wanted_2   wanted_3 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1    1    0    0    0    0    0          1          1          .          . |
  2. |  2    1    1    0    0    0    0          2          .          1          . |
  3. |  3    1    1    1    0    0    0          3          .          .          1 |
  4. |  4    1    1    1    0    0    0          3          .          .          1 |
  5. |  5    0    1    0    0    0    0          1          1          .          . |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |  6    1    0    0    0    0    0          1          1          .          . |
  7. |  7    0    0    0    0    1    0          1          1          .          . |
  8. |  8    0    0    0    0    0    1          1          1          .          . |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

*/
```